# How to ignore duplicates when I import xlsx file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, roo

I'm working on a project and I have to import some `Phones` to my website. Each phone have an IMEI and a ref_number.

However, some of those `Phones`are already in the DB, which make the request longer and lead to an application error on Heroku.

Here's my `phones_controller.rb` :

```
def import_xlsx
  if params[:xlsx].nil?
    render :import_phones
  else
    filepath = params[:xlsx].path
    xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(filepath)
    xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(filepath)
    xlsx.default_sheet = xlsx.sheets.first
    csv = xlsx.to_csv
    csv_options = { col_sep: ',', headers: :first_row, quote_char: '"' }
    csv_new = CSV.new(csv)
    CSV.parse(csv, csv_options) do |row|
      p = Phone.new(imei: row[0], ref_number: row[1])
      p.imei.gsub(/\s+/, "")
      if p.valid?
        p.save!
      else
        flash[:alert] = "#{p.imei}"
      end
    end
  redirect_to phones_import_path, notice: 'Votre fichier à bien été envoyer'
end
```

end

So, is there a way to do that or maybe to make the request faster ?

Comment: JFYI, that gsub does nothing

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev, you should put `p.imei = p.imei.gsub(/\s+/,"")` instead. Oh, and you can refactor the whole if-else to just `flash[:alert] = "#{p.imei}" unless p.save`.

Answer (score 3):

in the `Phone` model you could add a uniqueness validator like this:

```
validate :imei, uniqueness: true
```

so that, when you try to save the phone, it won't pass validations and won't be saved. In this case, it's a validator of duplicate fields.

[More info on validators](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_record_validations.html)